# How many spool space in tera data should I set for reading a 1 MB CSV file in S3 storage?

Tags: amazon-s3, teradata

I have a 1MB CSV file in S3 storage， I create a foreign table for it in tera data.

I set the spool size  to 1000 MB  in tera data,

```
modify user nos_usr as spool= 1000048576 bytes;
```

still  get the the error message:  spool size is not enough.

What's wrong ?  Spool size is already 1000 times to the size of 1 MB CSV file.

This doesn't make sense. Who knows why?   How many spool space size should I set it ?

Comment: Does User nos_usr have a Profile assigned? If so the profile spool limit overrides the user spool. Does your FOREIGN TABLE specify a very large VARCHAR length for the fields? Column values might be expanded / padded to the stated max length in spool in some cases, e.g. sort keys.

Comment: OK   I'll  Try  it  as  you said.  thanks